# Multiple Pattern using Regex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am a beginner for Python programming. I am exploring Regex. I am trying to Extract a word(Database name) from the Description column. I am not able to give multiple Regex patterns.

please see the description and the code below.

## Description

```
Summary: AD1: Low free DATA space in database AD1ADS: 10.00% Date: 06/28/2017 Severity: Warning Res
Summary: Database SV1V1CH has used log space: 90.00% Date: 02/06/2017 Severity: Warning ResourceId: s
Summary: SAP SolMan Sys=SM1Tempdb,MO=AGEEPM49,Alert=Database Host Status,Desc=A database hos
*** Clearing Event Received *** SNG01AMMSOL04_age SAP SolMan Sys=SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04,MO=AGEEQM46,Alert
```

## Expected Ouput of DB Names Extracted

```
AD1ADS
SV1V1CH
SM1Tempdb
SNG01AMMSOL04
```

## Code Tried

```
sentence = df['Description']
frame = pd.DataFrame({'logs': sentence})

import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)')

for _, line in frame.iterrows():
    name = pattern.findall(line['logs'])
    if name:
        line['names'] = name[0]
    else:
        line['names'] = 'Miscellaneous'
```

Could anyone please tell me, what mistake I am doing it here.

## Output which I am getting Now

```
(u'AD1ADS', u'')
(u'SV1V1CH', u'')
(u'', u'CM1_CHE01AMMSOL04')
Miscellaneous
```

Comment: what output are you getting? please post that as well

Comment: Please see the edited one. I have posted my answers as well

Comment: look @jezrael 's answer, that's how you can do it in pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
p = r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)'
s = df['logs'].str.extract(p, expand=True)
print (s)
         0                  1
0   AD1ADS                NaN
1  SV1V1CH                NaN
2      NaN          SM1Tempdb
3      NaN  SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04

df['db'] = s[0].fillna(s[1]).fillna('Miscellaneous')
#alternatively 
#df['db'] = s[0].combine_first(s[1]).fillna('Miscellaneous')
print (df)
                                                logs                 db
0  Summary: AD1: Low free DATA space in database ...             AD1ADS
1  Summary: Database SV1V1CH has used log space: ...            SV1V1CH
2  Summary: SAP SolMan Sys=SM1Tempdb,MO=AGEEPM49,...          SM1Tempdb
3  *** Clearing Event Received *** SNG01AMMSOL04_...  SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04
```

And if want extract all possible values use [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and then `join` them if necessary:

```
p = r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)'
s = df['logs'].str.extractall(p)
print (s)
               0                  1
  match                            
0 0       AD1ADS                NaN
1 0      SV1V1CH                NaN
2 0          NaN          SM1Tempdb
  1         Host                NaN
  2          hos                NaN
3 0          NaN  SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04

df['db'] = s[0].fillna(s[1]).groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
df['db'] = df['db'].fillna('Miscellaneous')
print (df)
                                                logs                    db
0  Summary: AD1: Low free DATA space in database ...                AD1ADS
1  Summary: Database SV1V1CH has used log space: ...               SV1V1CH
2  Summary: SAP SolMan Sys=SM1Tempdb,MO=AGEEPM49,...  SM1Tempdb, Host, hos
3  *** Clearing Event Received *** SNG01AMMSOL04_...     SM1_SNG01AMMSOL04
```

Comment: p = r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)| SAP: (\w+)'
    s = frame['logs'].str.extract(p, expand=True)
    print (s)

    frame['DBNames'] = s[0].fillna(s[1])
    frame['DBNames'] = s[0].fillna(s[2])                                                      Can I modify as below, fo multiple condition

Comment: Thanks Ashish and @jezrael

Comment: @BPK - do you want for multiple condition new columns? For each pattaern one new column?

Comment: Yes. As of now, I am able to see columns, 0 and 1 for two match conditions and combined it using            df['db'] = s[0].fillna(s[1]).groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)                                                   But, now adding another condition, say -  p = r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)|SAP: (\w+)'      How can I combine 0,1 and 2. replacing the NAs

Comment: I get it, need `s.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1).groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)` - it working with multiple columns nice

Answer (score 1):

```
p = r'[dD]atabase (\w+)|Sys=(\w+)|SAP: (\w+)'
s = df['logs'].str.extractall(p)
print (s)

df['DBNames'] = s.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()),axis=1).groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
df['DBNames'] = df['DBNames'].fillna('Miscellaneous')
print df
```

This worked for me :)